# Make target using a pattern

Tags: makefile

I'm doing something which it feels like should be pretty straightforward. I have source files in a directory called `./src` which are transformed and saved to `./`. *For the sake of the question, I'll just say they get copied there.*

Here's what the directory looks like before building:

```
/src/lib/foo.js
/src/lib/mod/bar.js
/src/bin/baz.js
/Makefile
```

Here's what should be there after building:

```
/src/lib/foo.js
/src/lib/mod/bar.js
/src/bin/baz.js
/lib/foo.js
/lib/mod/bar.js
/bin/baz.js
/Makefile
```

In my Makefile I have this:

```
SRC_FILES := src/lib/foo.js src/lib/mod/bar.js src/bin/baz.js
OUT_FILES := lib/foo.js lib/mod/bar.js bin/baz.js
```

*These are generated from `find` and a pattern substitution, but are listed like this here for simplicity...*

Now, what I was hoping would work would be:

```
%.js: src/%.js
    cp $< $@
```

But when I run `make lib/foo.js` I get `Nothing to be done for 'lib/foo.js'.`

Looking at the output from debugging, it appears to be trying to find a dependency named `lib/src/foo.js`. This is kind of what is described in [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Match.html#Pattern-Match).

This feels as though it should be a really easy thing! What am I doing wrong?

---

Additionally, I tried:

```
$(OUT_FILES): $(SRC_FILES)
    cp $< $@
```

...which works, but it rebuilds every single file if any of the sources change. *(Remember that my actual transformation isn't just `cp`, it's a relatively expensive operation, so this is undesirable)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found something which works. Using secondary expansion, you have access to the target variable in the dependencies. I saw this earlier, but missed the all-important thing: adding an empty target called `.SECONDEXPANSION`

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

all: $(OUT_FILES)

%.js: src/$$@
    cp $< $@
```